# problems with ejs(data.forEach is not a function)!

Tags: javascript, foreach, ejs

Hello so i am trying to run a javascript function inside of a ejs file and this is what my code looks like :

```
<div class='row'>

<% data.forEach( function( items ) {  %>

    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>
        <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="<%= items.img %>" width="350" height="130"></img>    

         <div class="caption">
            <h4><%= items.partname %></h4>
        </div>
        </div>



    </div>

<% }); %>

</div>
```

when i try and run this inside my ejs file i get this error as a return "
 36| 
   37|

> > 38| <% data.forEach(function(items){ %>
> >        39|
> >        40|     
> >        41|

data.forEach is not a function
   at eval (eval at

does anyone know how to fix this?

this is the backend for my code above:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
  app.set("view engine","ejs");

var chairSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    partname:String,
    img:String,
    price:Number
});

var data =mongoose.model("data",chairSchema);

data.create(
{
  partname:"short cylinder",
  img:"http://www.needforseatusa.com/assets/images/products/replacement%20parts/short_cylinder_thumbnail.jpg",
  price:14.90
},
{
  partname:"regular cylinder",
  img:"http://www.needforseatusa.com/assets/images/products/replacement%20parts/cylinder_thumbnail.jpg",
  price:14.90
},{
  partname:"back pillow",
  img:"http://www.needforseatusa.com/assets/images/products/replacement%20parts/lumbar_pillow_thumbnail.jpg",
  price:29.90
},{
  partname:"head pillow",
  img:"http://www.needforseatusa.com/assets/images/products/replacement%20parts/head_pillow_thumbnail.jpg",
  price:29.90
},{
  partname:"wheel base chrome",
  img:"http://www.needforseatusa.com/assets/images/products/accessories/hd-base-black_thumbnail.jpg",
  price:79.99
},{
  partname:"wheel base black",
  img:"http://www.needforseatusa.com/assets/images/products/accessories/hd_base_)1_thumbnail.jpg",
  price:79.99
},function(err,chair){
  if (err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  else{
    console.log("newly created chair");
    console.log(data);
  }

}


);
app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render('landing');
});


app.get("/campground",function(req,res){
   data.find({},function(err,data){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }

    });

   res.render("campground", {data:data}); 
});
```

Comment: You have to verify your backend request. This front end code is good. That data variable is either not being passed or has problems with it. What do you get if you console.log(data) on the ejs page? Also post the backend request that'll be more useful

Comment: i have added the backend request

Comment: Is `data` an Array or Object?

Comment: I'm using EJS now and I was having the same issue. OP is trying to iterate through an object rather than an array. It's basically saying "data" is not something that you can loop through.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a sample example of using `foreach` with `ejs`, I want you to inspect that data you are sending back to `ejs`, if it's an Array. Otherwise make sure it is, because `foreach` is an Array method.

```
var data = {    
  title: 'Cleaning Supplies',
  supplies: ['mop', 'broom', 'duster']  
};
```

**ejs**

```
<ul>
<% data.supplies.forEach(function(value) { %>
   <li><%= value %></li>
<% }) %>
</ul>

// mop
// broom
// duster
```

Comment: ah I think I finally understand. Basically, you have to know what type of data you are trying to present. If it's an array then he forEach should work but if it's an object and you try to iterate through it then you will get the error OP presented.

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

if you use node js for get data from database, use **async** and **awit** ,
because you send data to ejs file without any value in it

Comment: please make your answer more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was how I sent the data to the view.

So after I had queried the database, as in

```js
db.getTasks()
    .then(results => res.render('view', { results: results }))
    .catch(err => ...)
```

I returned the result to the view and not the rows, `results.rows` to the view.
Just by adding .`.rows` to the result solve my problem

```js
db.getTasks()
    .then(results => res.render('view', { results: results.rows }))
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

My server.js had the following code:

```
res.render('index', articles: 'articles')
```

When I removed the strings from the second articles, the error went away. By the way the articles were in curly braces.